# ArrayList: how does the size increase?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I have a basic question on Java `ArrayList`.

When `ArrayList` is declared and initialized using the default constructor, memory space for 10 elements is created. Now, when I add an 11th element, what happens? Will new memory space be created with 20 (or more) element capacity (this requires copying elements from 1st memory location to new location) OR some thing else?

I checked the `ArrayList` API documentation for Java 1.4.2. But I didn't find an answer.

Please share the knowledge.
Thanks.

Edit: New links:

- [`ArrayList` in the Java 11 API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [Java(TM) 2 SDK, Standard Edition Documentation 1.4.2](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-142docs-downloads.html)

Comment: The best way to find out is to actually read the source code. But beware. Here be dragons.

Comment: [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java)'s the source of ArrayList from OpenJDK 6. Be aware there are many implementations of it (GNU Classpath, Apache Harmony, OpenJDK, ...) and they may differ.

Comment: Most implementation grow by a factor of 1.5x: https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/03/19/java-arraylist/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A new array is created and the contents of the old one are copied over. That's all you know at the API level. Quoting from [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (my emphasis):

> Each `ArrayList` instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. **The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost.**

In terms of how it actually happens with a specific implementation of `ArrayList` (such as Sun's), in their case you can see the gory details in the source. But of course, relying on the details of a specific implementation isn't usually a good idea...

Comment: A new array will be  created and the contents of the old one will be copied over.  so what will happen to old array either it will be in memory or deleted?

Comment: @VikasKumarSingh: The old one becomes eligible for garbage collection, like any object that no longer has anything referencing it. When (or even if) that happens is up to the JVM.

Comment: what happens to the old ArrayList from which the elements are copied? Does GC reclaims that memory?

Comment: @Ravi.Kumar: There is no old *ArrayList*, just an old array. Yes, the ArrayList releases its reference to the old array, which is the only reference to it, which means it's eligible for GC.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Is it at all possible(it should be) that allocation of new Array dynamically was not possible as that much memory is not present as contiguous locations? What does Java specify be done in such cases?

Comment: @Denson - Whenever the JVM can't allocate memory, it either just dies (or is so slow trying to allocate that it may as well have died), or it succeeds in throwing an [`OutOfMemoryError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html). Seems to me (from my experience *years* ago) is that it generally does manage to throw the error (having some memory set aside for that purpose), but YMMV.

Answer (score 47):

Sun's JDK6:

I believe that it grows to 15 elements. Not coding it out, but looking at the grow()
code in the jdk.

int newCapacity then = 10 + (10 >> 1) = 15.

```
/**
 * Increases the capacity to ensure that it can hold at least the
 * number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.
 *
 * @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
 */
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

From the Javadoc, it says this is from Java 2 and on, so its a safe bet in the Sun JDK.

**EDIT** : for those who didn't get what's the connection between multiplying factor `1.5` and `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);`

`>>` is right shift operator which reduces a number to its half.
Thus,
 `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);`
=> `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + 0.5*oldCapacity;` 
=> `int newCapacity = 1.5*oldCapacity ;`

Comment: yes, reading the source code is the best way to understand the behavior. I have also read the code and got the same answer. This is true for the jdk 8.

Answer (score 33):

It will depend on the implementation, but from the Sun Java 6 source code:

```
int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
```

That's in the `ensureCapacity` method. Other JDK implementations may vary.

Comment: What if we the numerator value is an odd number? So, for example, the old capacity is 25, then newCapacity = (25*3)/2 + 1 = 75 / 2 + 1 =  37.5 + 1 = 38.5.
So, a capacity of 38.5 is not valid right, so how does the newCapacity get allocated?

Comment: Integer arithmetic rounds towards zero, so in your example the new capacity will be 38. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2

Answer (score 16):

Up to JDK 6 the the capacity grow with formula `newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3/2) + 1`.

In JDK 7 and above the formula changes to `newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1)`.

So if initial capacity is `10` then new capacity will be `16 in JDK6` and `15 in above JDK7`

Answer (score 14):

When we try to add an object to the arraylist,

**Java checks** to ensure that there is enough capacity in the existing array to hold the new object. If not, a **new array of a greater size is created**, the **old array is copied to new array** using **Arrays.copyOf** and the new array is assigned to the existing array.

Look at the code below (taken from Java ArrayList Code at GrepCode.com).

[image: Check this example]

[image]

> Edit:

**public ArrayList()** Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten.

**public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)** we can specify initial capacity.

**public ArrayList(Collection c)** Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Now when we use ArrayList() constructore we get a ArrayList with **Size=10**
On adding 11th element in the list new Arraylist is created inside ensureCapacity() method.

Using following formula:

```
  int newCapacity= (oldCapacity * 3)/2 +1;
```

Comment: that movement :) when you get your answer in google search after nearly 2 years

Answer (score 10):

Lets look at this test case (jdk1.8)

```
@Test
    public void testArraySize() throws Exception {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("ds");
        list.add("cx");
        list.add("cx");
        list.add("ww");
        list.add("ds");
        list.add("cx");
        list.add("cx");
        list.add("ww");
        list.add("ds");
        list.add("cx");
        list.add("last");
    }
```

1)Put break point on the line when "last" is inserted

2)Go to the add method of `ArrayList`
You will see

```
ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
        elementData[size++] = e;
```

3. Go to ensureCapacityInternal method, this method calls `ensureExplicitCapacity`
4. private void ensureExplicitCapacity(int minCapacity) {
   modCount++;

   ```
         // overflow-conscious code
         if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
             grow(minCapacity);
     }
             return true;
   ```

In our example minCapacity is equal to 11 `11-10 > 0` therefore   `grow` method will be called

5)

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
        // overflow-conscious code
        int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
        int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
        if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
            newCapacity = minCapacity;
        if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
            newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
        // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    }
```

Lets describe each step:

1. `oldCapacity` = 10 by default, in java 8 arraylist's capacity is 10 , you can override it by passing another value in constructor
2. `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);`
   Here newCapacity is equal to oldCapacity plus oldCapacity with right shift by one
   (`oldCapacity is 10` this is the binary representation `00001010` moving one bit to right will make `00000101` which is 5 in decimal therefore `newCapacity` is `10 + 5 = 15`)
3. if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
   newCapacity = minCapacity;
   For example your initial capacity was 1(`new ArrayList<>(1)`), when you add the second element `newCapacity` will be equal to `1(oldCapacity) + 0 (moved to right by one bit) = 1`
   In this case newCapacity is less than minCapacity and `elementData`( objects array`Object[]` inside arrayList that stores the data) can't hold new element therefore newCapacity will be equal to minCapacity
4. if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
   newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);

Check if array size reached MAX_ARRAY_SIZE (which is Integer.MAX - 8) [Why the maximum array size of ArrayList is Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756277/why-the-maximum-array-size-of-arraylist-is-integer-max-value-8)

5. Finally it copies old values to the newArray with length 15

Answer (score 7):

when a ArrayList is declared and initialized using default 
constructor, memory space for 10 elements will be created.
now, when i add 11 th element, what happens is

ArrayList create a new object with the following size

i.e  OldCapacity*3/2+1 = 10*3/2+1 =16

Answer (score 5):

Typically, the memory for ArrayList type containers is increased by doubling it. Thus, if you initially had space for 10 items and you added 10, the eleventh item will be added to a new (internal) array of 20 items. The reason for this is that the incremental cost of adding items is reduced from O(n^2) if the array had been incremented in fixed size increments to a nice O(n) when doubling the size each time the internal array is full.

Answer (score 4):

> When ArrayList is declared and initialized using the default constructor, memory space for 10 elements is created.

NO. When ArrayList is initialized, memory allocation is made for an empty array. Memory allocation for default capacity (10) is made only upon addition of first element to ArrayList.

```
 /**
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
 * empty ArrayList with elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA will be expanded to
 * DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
 */
private transient Object[] elementData;
```

P.S. Don't have enough reputation to comment on question, so I am putting this as an answer as nobody pointed out this incorrect assumption earlier.

Answer (score 3):

> Context java 8

I give my answer here in the context of Oracle java 8 implementation, since after reading all the answers, I found that an answer in the context of java 6 has given by gmgmiller, and another answer has been given in the context of java 7.  But how java 8 implementes the size increasement has not been given.

In java 8, the size increasement behavior is the same as java 6, see the `grow` method of ArrayList:

```
   private void grow(int minCapacity) {
        // overflow-conscious code
        int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
        int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
        if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
            newCapacity = minCapacity;
        if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
            newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
        // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    }
```

the key code is this line:

```
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
```

So clearly, the growth factor is also 1.5, the same as java 6.

Comment: For the people who can't get the derivation for "1.5". Considering oldCapacity  as x, Then newCapacity = x + x/(2^1) = x +x/2 = 1.5x

Comment: The operator '>>', which does sign extension while shifting, may be a little confusing for the some, because it is not considered to be used as the div operator, due to not working with negative values. In this case it just works due to length being always >=0. As as div operator '>>>' should be used mainly.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList does increases the size on load factor on following cases:

- **Initial Capacity:** 10
- **Load Factor:** 1 (i.e. when the list is full)
- **Growth Rate:** current_size + current_size/2

> Context : JDK 7

While adding an element into the `ArrayList`, the following `public ensureCapacityInternal` calls and the other private method calls happen internally to increase the size. This is what dynamically increase the size of `ArrayList`. 
while viewing the code you can understand the logic by naming conventions, because of this reason I am not adding explicit description

```
public boolean add(E paramE) {
        ensureCapacityInternal(this.size + 1);
        this.elementData[(this.size++)] = paramE;
        return true;
    }

private void ensureCapacityInternal(int paramInt) {
        if (this.elementData == EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA)
            paramInt = Math.max(10, paramInt);
        ensureExplicitCapacity(paramInt);
    }
private void ensureExplicitCapacity(int paramInt) {
        this.modCount += 1;
        if (paramInt - this.elementData.length <= 0)
            return;
        grow(paramInt);
    }

private void grow(int paramInt) {
    int i = this.elementData.length;
    int j = i + (i >> 1);
    if (j - paramInt < 0)
        j = paramInt;
    if (j - 2147483639 > 0)
        j = hugeCapacity(paramInt);
    this.elementData = Arrays.copyOf(this.elementData, j);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static int getCapacity(ArrayList<?> list) throws Exception {
            Field dataField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
            dataField.setAccessible(true);
            return ((Object[]) dataField.get(list)).length;
    }
```

use the above method to check the size when the arraylist is being modified.

Answer (score 1):

From JDK source code, I found below code

```
int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList in Java grows by 50% of its original capacity once it is full.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What new information does this answer add compared to the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

What happens is a new Array is created with n*2 spaces, then all items in the old array are copied over and the new item is inserted in the first free space.  All in all, this results in O(N) add time for the ArrayList.

If you're using Eclipse, install [Jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) and [Jadclipse](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to decompile the JARs held in the library.  I did this to read the original source code.

Answer (score 0):

Size of `ArrayList` increases with `n+n/2+1` always.

Comment: Can you add some explanation ? it's a quite short

Answer (score 0):

Default capacity of ArrayList is 10.
Once the Capacity reaches its maximum capacity, Size of the ArrayList will be 16, once the capacity reaches its maximum capacity of 16, size of the ArrayList will be 25 and keep on increasing based on Data size.....

How? Here is the Answer and Formula

```
New capacity = (Current Capacity * 3/2) + 1
```

So, if the default capacity is 10, then

```
Current Capacity = 10
New capacity = (10 * 3/2) + 1
Output is 16
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jdk 1.6:
New capacity = (Current Capacity * 3/2) + 1;

In Jdk 1.7:

int j = i + (i >> 1);
this is same as 
New capacity = (Current Capacity * 1/2) + Current Capacity;

ex:size will increase like :10-->15-->22-->33

Answer (score 0):

**(oldSize * 3)/2 + 1**

*If you are using default constructor then initial size of `ArrayList` will be `10` else you can pass the initial size of array while creating the object of `ArrayList`.*

Example: In case default constructor

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.size()
```

*Example: In case parameterized constructor*

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
list.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Arraylist default capacity is 10.
2. [1,2,3,4,5.....10]
3. if you want to increase the size of Arraylist in java, you can apply this
4. formula-
5. int newcapacity, current capacity;
6. newcapacity =((current capacity*3/2)+1)
7. arralist will be [1,2,3,4,5.....10,11] and arraylist capacity is 16.

Comment: Hi Shobha and Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not insert your whole answer in a code block. Please use code blocks only for code and leave text outside. Moreover, you might want to test your code before pasting it: you cannot use blank space in a variable name, so `current capacity` is not a variable and your code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

This is the lastest JDK version (2022 June), JDK 18, and you can download it on https://jdk.java.net/18/
or we can look the source on Github
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

When you add an item into your ArrayList, Java will ensure that it can hold at least the items was in it and the new item. Java prefer to increase the capacity to 1.5* current capacity according to this expression

```
int newCapacity = ArraysSupport.newLength(oldCapacity,
                minCapacity - oldCapacity, /* minimum growth */
                oldCapacity >> 1           /* preferred growth */);.
```

`oldCapacity >> 1` means 0.5 * oldCapacity
so newLength will be 1.5 * oldCapacity if it is positive and not overflow

Here are the code snippets:

src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    modCount++;
    add(e, elementData, size);
    return true;
}

private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}

private Object[] grow() {
    return grow(size + 1);
}

private Object[] grow(int minCapacity) {
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    if (oldCapacity > 0 || elementData != DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
        int newCapacity = ArraysSupport.newLength(oldCapacity,
                minCapacity - oldCapacity, /* minimum growth */
                oldCapacity >> 1           /* preferred growth */);
        return elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    } else {
        return elementData = new Object[Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity)];
    }
}
```

src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/util/ArraysSupport.java

```
public static int newLength(int oldLength, int minGrowth, int prefGrowth) {
    int prefLength = oldLength + Math.max(minGrowth, prefGrowth); // might overflow
    if (0 < prefLength && prefLength <= SOFT_MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH) {
        return prefLength;
    } else {
        return hugeLength(oldLength, minGrowth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on implementation but for OpenJDK 21 it is this:

```java
private Object[] grow(int minCapacity) {
        int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
        if (oldCapacity > 0 || elementData != DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA) {
            int newCapacity = ArraysSupport.newLength(oldCapacity,
                    minCapacity - oldCapacity, /* minimum growth */
                    oldCapacity >> 1           /* preferred growth */);
            return elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
        } else {
            return elementData = new Object[Math.max(DEFAULT_CAPACITY, minCapacity)];
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.lang.Object**

If reflections do not work for you (i.e. when using dataField.setAccessible(true)), one option is to use your IDE debug tool.

Picture of IDE and breakpoint:

[image]

Once you reach line 20 in picture, then put a breakpoint in class ArrayList.java, line 467:

[image]

Step until you can reach the following to read capacity:

[image]

Used java version:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

ArrayList is the class of  Collection Interface.
Java is open source language we can change its implementation.
here java predefined implementation is:
new capacity = (currentCapacity*3)/2 + 1;
or
in JAVASE8
newcapacity = oldCapacity+(oldcapacity>>1);

Comment: This is the same as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52355461/2227743).

Answer (score -3):

The default size of the arraylist is 10. When we add the 11th ....arraylist increases the size (n*2). The values stored in old arraylist are copied into the new arraylist whose size is 20.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that hasn't been said in the original answers from 2010.

Comment: When you add 11th elements capacity will be 15 not 20.