# Why the maximum array size of ArrayList is Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am studying Java 8 documentation for `ArrayList`. I got that maximum array size is defined as `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8` means 2^31 – 8 = **2 147 483 639**. Then I have focused on why 8 is subtracted or `why not less than 8` or `more than 8` is subtracted?

```
/**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate.
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
```

I got some related answers but not fulfilling my thrust.

1. [Do Java arrays have a maximum size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)
2. [How many data a list can hold at the maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767979/how-many-data-a-list-can-hold-at-the-maximum)
3. [Why I can't create an array with large size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382531/why-i-cant-create-an-array-with-large-size)

Some people given some logic that as per documentation `"Some VMs reserve some header words in an array"`. So for header words, 8 is subtracted. But on that case, if header words need more than 8, then what will be the answer?

Please clarify me on that basis. Advance thanks for your cooperation.

Comment: If more than 8 header words are needed, then it'd crash when it got that big.  So 8 is the ArrayList author's estimate of the maximum number of extra header words that'd be needed.

Comment: On an unrelated note: if you're allocating an array with 2 billions elements, there is probably something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - in VM 8 bytes is more high? If possible, please let me know.

Comment: @SkyWalker, that sentence makes no sense.  Also, it's 8 bytes, not 8 bits, which is _lots_ of room for headers.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I got that. So it will not exceed 8 bytes for header of VM

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size for more info

Comment: Someone has given downvote but no comments. Would you please clarify and share the reason so that we can be more proactive to ask a question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read the above article about [Java Memory management](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-codetoheap/index.html), which clearly states

I think this applies to ArrayList as it is the Resizable array implemenation.

**Anatomy of a Java array object**

> The shape and structure of an array object, such as an array of int
>   values, is similar to that of a standard Java object. The primary
>   difference is that the array object has an additional piece of
>   metadata that denotes the array's size. An array object's metadata,
>   then, consists of: Class : A pointer to the class information, which
>   describes the object type. In the case of an array of int fields, this
>   is a pointer to the int[] class.
>
> Flags : A collection of flags that describe the state of the object,
>   including the hash code for the object if it has one, and the shape of
>   the object (that is, whether or not the object is an array).
>
> Lock : The synchronization information for the object — that is,
>   whether the object is currently synchronized.
>
> Size : The size of the array.

max size

```
2^31 = 2,147,483,648
```

as the Array it self needs `8 bytes` to stores the size 
`2,147,483,648`

so

```
2^31 -8 (for storing size ),
```

so maximum array size is defined as Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8

Comment: for 32bit and 64 bit java process, does array needs 8 bytes on both case ?

Comment: Since object sizes are rounded up to a multiple of 8 bytes, yes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 7` since `Integer.MAX_VALUE == 2^31 - 1`?

Answer (score 6):

**The size of object header can not exceed 8 byte.**

**For HotSpot:**

The object header consists of `a mark word` and `a klass pointer`.

**The mark word** has word size (4 byte on 32 bit architectures, 8 byte on 64 bit architectures) and

**the klass pointer** has word size on `32 bit` architectures. On `64 bit` architectures the klass pointer either has word size, but can also have `4 byte` if the heap addresses can be encoded in these `4 bytes`.

This optimization is called **"compressed oops"** and you can also control it with the option UseCompressedOops.

[What is in java object header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357186/what-is-in-java-object-header)

Answer (score 4):

The value is a worst-case scenario. Note the comment:

> Attempts to allocate larger arrays ***may*** result in OutOfMemoryError

It doesn't say *will*, just *may*. If you stay below this value, you should have no issue (as long as memory is available, of course).

You may want to look at the answers to this question for more information:
[Why I can't create an array with large size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31382531/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

integer max size is :
2^31 - 1 = 2,147,483,648 - 1

Integer.java:
@Native public static final int   MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;