# Java Spring : MongoRepository count() and findAll()

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

I have noticed something weird in Spring data for mongo :

`MongoRepository` extends `CrudRepository` and the `findAll()` returns an `Iterable` which it's ok with the `count()` method as it returns a `long`.

```java
class CrudRepository {

  ...

  Iterable<T> findAll();

  long count();
}
```

In mongo `MongoRepository` the `findAll()` method returs a `List` :

```java
class MongoRepository extends CrudRepository {

  ...  

  @Override
  List<T> findAll();
}
```

But a `List#size()` returns an `int` and the `MongoRepository#count()` method stay returning a long.

What happens when the collection exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` !? Could we still call `List<T> findAll()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I liked your view point :) This question looks similar based on what you're asking to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756277/why-the-maximum-array-size-of-arraylist-is-integer-max-value-8)

As it mentioned in Java Language Specification: *[15.10.1. Array Creation Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1):*

> Each dimension expression undergoes unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1). The promoted type must be int, or a compile-time error occurs.

Since dimension has to be an int, we can stores maximum the size `2,147,483,648` in an array and also considering an ArrayList is nothing else but an Array, we can not store more than INTEGER.MAX_VALUE in an ArrayList. (Different implementations of List could behave differently, of course)

[Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-return-types) allows you to customize query methods. You are always free to create a query method which returns type is Iterable.

```
@Override
Iterable<T> findAll();
```

Answer (score 3):

From [`java.util.List#size`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--) javadoc:

> Returns the number of elements in this list. **If this list contains more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.**

So when collection size exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE` the `size` method will return `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

> Could we still call `List<T> findAll()`?

Yes, but most probably the call will fail with `OutOfMemoryError`