# Implement a list with o(1) running time

Tags: java, algorithm, time, implementation

Could I make a list with everything having fast running time? Is it possible having this type of list? I can't wrap my head around how you could keep search or add times being constant if it needs to go through nodes to search for others, much less adding.

Comment: What do you mean by "that beats the purpose of having a list"?

Comment: If you used an expanding list that doubles in size as you need it, you could achieve amortized O(1) getting, setting, and adding, which just means you'd eventually need to expand its size, but that doesn't happen often enough. Pretty sure this is how Java's ArrayList class works.

Comment: "I can't wrap my head around how you could keep search or add times at o(1)" Also, search time would NOT be O(1). Only get, set, and add.

Comment: *I can't wrap my head around how you could keep search or add times at o(1)*. Who said anything about search times?

Comment: @failed.down Talking to me? I read the question... obviously. My question was directed to OP.

Comment: @shmosel I believe OP is just misusing the word `searching` to mean `get()` or `indexed-access`

Comment: @AdrianShum I suspect the same. It's led to a lot of pointless discussion in the answers and comments.

Comment: Just want to clarify: is `add()` here means only `add(E element)` (adding to the end of list, or also `add(int index, E element)` (adding to a specific index)?  If it includes the latter case, then I don't think there is any solution (yet).  If you only need former case, then `ArrayList` is already serving your purpose (explained in other answer)

Comment: @Glen Pierce what I mean by that is that I feel the point of a list is searching by links. If you're going to search by hashing, is that really a list?

Comment: @Kaz "with references to the order and to pointers, but that beats the purpose of having a list"... I'm confused as to why you think I don't think that means he intends to " maintain a sequence of elements, in which successors and predecessor relationships are clearly identified and maintained". You're being remarkably rude for someone with a public profile.

Answer (score 1):

At first you only said get(), add() and set(), but then you said search() as well.  The first three all have O(1) average run time in an ArrayList and similar implementations.  You can't have O(1) search time in anything that would normally be considered a list.

Edit:  Some people have pointed out, correctly, that you could get O(1) lookup time if the list implementation also stored element indices in a hashmap. Strictly speaking, as long as it implements a List interface, it is a list.  I should have said that you can't do that with *only* a list.

Comment: Unless the list was indexed with a hash table.

Comment: @selbie Then it wouldn't be a list.

Comment: @shmosel You could extend `ArrayList` and override `indexOf` to be backed by a `HashMap<E,Integer>`, unless does using a hash table in the implementation automatically make it not a list?

Comment: @4castle That's actually a neat idea. My point is that an array list and hash table are separate data structures. Sure, they can share a roof to reduce time complexity (at an increased memory and write cost), so maybe it's a "`java.util.List` with O(1) search time", but I wouldn't call it a "list [structure] with O(1) search time".

Comment: But what about when you run out of space and have to rehash? That takes O(n) times (n being the number of elements you have)

Comment: Expanding the inner array in a hashmap takes O(n), but only occurs O(1/n) of the time, so insertion is still O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my comment as an answer...

If you used an expanding list that expands in size as you need it, you could achieve **amortized** O(1) `get`ting, `set`ting, and `add`ing, which just means you'd eventually need to expand its size, but that doesn't happen often enough. Pretty sure this is how Java's ArrayList class works.

You can read more about it here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4450659/1572906

You mentioned searching, but with this kind of approach, O(1) doesn't seem very feasible. You could achieve O(1) using a hash table alongside the array.

Comment: Hash tables are generally considered to be O(1) in the amortized/average case.  So search could be O(1) ...

Comment: HashSet `put()` and `get()` are both _O(1)_. TreeSet is _O(log n)_

Comment: `add()` in `ArrayList` may be `O(n)`, as there is an `add(int index, E element)`.  It is `O(1)` only if you only consider adding at the end of list.  I believe OP should be clearer on his question

Comment: my bad, you're right. i fixed it; idk what i was thinking